# Angular 1.2 not show Adsense Ads

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, adsense

After October 26th we encountered such a problem.

when changing the route Advertising (Google Adsense) is not shown, it is absolutely empty, although requests for advertising are

If you just refresh the page - advertising is shown everywhere

I tried:

1. Add a random number to Add a random number to
2. When changing the route, call this function.

Function:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
         Object.keys($window).filter(function(k) { return k.indexOf('google') >= 0 }).forEach(
             function(key) {
                 delete($window[key]);
             }
         );
     });
```

I Use

Angular v1.2.26

Angular UI router v0.2.10

Thank you in advance